# How XCTestExpectation should be initialized?

Tags: swift, xctest

There's 2 options how to initialize `XCTestExpectation`. First, with direct initializer.

```
import XCTest

class MyTests: XCTestCase {
    let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "foo")`
}
```

And second using `XCTest` instance method.

```
import XCTest

class MyTests: XCTestCase {
    let expectation = self.expectation(description: "foo")
}
```

2 methods produce same result, so I wonder which is better to use? Is direct `XCTestExpectation` initializer a bit faster?

Answer (score 2):

The biggest difference is if you want to use `waitForExpectations(timeout: TimeInterval, handler: XCWaitCompletionHandler)` or not.

`waitForExpectations(timeout: TimeInterval, handler: XCWaitCompletionHandler)` can only be used if the expectations were created with `self.expectation(description: "foo")`.

Otherwise, you need to call `wait(for expectations: [XCTestExpectation], timeout seconds: TimeInterval)`